# Training multiple output softmax probability vectors in keras neural network

Tags: keras

I have built the model shown below. I have shaped my Y-data to the size of `(?,3,11)`.

One y-data sample is shown below:

```
[[0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 1. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0.]
 [0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 0. 1. 0. 0.]]
```

[image]

Yet, in training, I receive the following error:

```
ValueError: Shapes (8, 3, 11) and (8, 11) are incompatible
```

Why does the neural network expects the Y-data to be `(?,11)`? This is the size of a single branch's output.

Here is the neural network, in code:

```py
def branch(inputs):
    x = Conv1D(filters=5, kernel_size=4, activation='relu')(inputs)
    x = Dropout(0.2)(x)
    x = MaxPooling1D(pool_size=2)(x)
    x = Flatten()(x)
    out = Dense(100)(x)
    out = Dense(11,activation='softmax')(x)
    return out

inputs = Input(shape=(28,9))
x = Conv1D(filters=10, kernel_size=4, activation='relu')(inputs)
outs = []
for _ in range(3):
    outs.append(branch(x))
self.model = Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outs)
self.model.compile(loss='categorical_crossentropy', optimizer='adam', metrics=['categorical_accuracy'])
```

Training code:

```py
cv = KFold(n_splits = n_split)
cvscores = []
for train_idx, test_idx in cv.split(self.X_train):
    ytr, yte = self.Y_train[train_idx], self.Y_train[test_idx]
    xtr, xte = self.X_train[train_idx], self.X_train[test_idx]
    history = self.model.fit(xtr, ytr, epochs=max_epochs, batch_size=batch_size, verbose = verbose)

    scores = self.model.evaluate(xte, yte, verbose=0)
```

Comment: There is a lot of missing information here, errors in isolation cannot be interpreted by us, you need to tell us how you are using the labels to train a multi-output model.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy I added a y-sample and the neural network code snippet

Comment: Instead of shaping 'y' as `[?,3,11]`, you need to pass three corresponding `[?,11]` y-data as `[y1,y2,y3]` in fit() or evaluate()/

Comment: Thanks @AshwinGeetD'Sa. I reshaped to `(3,?,11)` but am getting error: 
`ValueError: Data cardinality is ambiguous:
  x sizes: 1728
  y sizes: 3
Please provide data which shares the same first dimension.`

Comment: You shouldn't reshape. You should pass the list of y1,y2,y3 of shapes `[?,11]` in the fit function.